# How create a query to filter by the total sum of an table column mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I have a quantity of data that I want to filter depending on the sum of the data, an example to be clear: I have that table

```
Nombre | nit | cantidad 
andres | 222 | 1.5
joseff | 555 | 2
juanca | 777 | 3.5
ivanll | 999 | 4
amxsof | 111 | 6.1
```

The query would have to do is, ask from this table the rows whose **SUM of the cantidad column** is equal or less (but as close as possible) than 13, and I would return the following:

```
Nombre | Nit | Cantidad 
joseff | 555 | 2
ivanll | 999 | 4
amxsof | 111 | 6.1
```

because the sum of 2 + 4 + 6.1 = 12.1, which is the closest sum to 13 that can be done with the records

Comment: Do-able, but an RDBMS is possibly not the best tool for these sorts np complete problems

Comment: How many records do you have? Why do you need to do that?

Comment: @Strawberry, can be solved together php

Comment: @Olivier , there are more than 5000 records, it must be done because a we have a registration number has to be assigned to a limit number of cantidades, for example i have to the number RC1563 for 13 cantidades, then i need assign this RC1563 to the records that i can most

Comment: Well... Don't you realize the high combinatorial complexity of such a problem? Your question is not related to SQL. You should use the tag "algorithm" because it's the only one relevant here.

Comment: @Olivier, the unic way is with an algorithm?

Comment: Of course. And it will probably take a long time to run.

Comment: Also, what version of MySQL

Comment: Actually, the closest to 13 is ivanl, joseff, and juanca -- which exactly sums to 13.

Answer (score 0):

SQL is not optimal for this type of optimization problem.  You can do it, but it is brute force.

It also helps if you are limiting the number of rows that you are considering.  For instance, if you are considering combinations up to 4:

```
select t1.nombre, t2.nombre, t3.nombre, t4.nombre,
       (coalesce(t1.cantidad, 0) + coalesce(t2.cantidad, 0) + coalesce(t3.cantidad, 0) + coalesce(t4.cantidad, 0)
       ) as total
from t t1 left join
     t t2
     on t1.nombre < t2.nombre left join
     t t3
     on t2.nombre < t3.nombre left join
     t t4
     on t3.nombre < t4.nombre
where (coalesce(t1.cantidad, 0) + coalesce(t2.cantidad, 0) + coalesce(t3.cantidad, 0) + coalesce(t4.cantidad, 0)
       ) <= 13
order by total desc
limit 1;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=14b6e2ed556c8d86c4a07caa93738099) is a db<>fiddle.

If you want to consider additional combinations, you can add additional joins.

Comment: Your query is incorrect (it gives a wrong answer). And even if it was correct, a join between 4 tables with 5000 records each needs to fetch 5000^4 = 6.25e+14 records.

Comment: @Olivier . . . Did you look at the db<>fiddle?  The numbers add up to 13, which is what the OP wants.  By the way, your calculation on the number of records is off, although not by that much.  You also seem to be not reading the first sentence of the answer.

Comment: Yes, I looked at the fiddle. 4 + 2 + 3.5 is not equal to 13.